How pass extent-config.xml from Jar while using pulgin com.aventstack.extentreports.cumcumber.adapter.ExtendCucumberAdapter?
I have folder structure
project-root
│
├── src
│   ├── main
│   │   └── java
│   │       └── com.example.package
│   │            └── Main.java (Cucumber CLI usage)
│   └── test
│       ├── java
│       │   └── com.example.package
│       │       └── runner
│       │           └── YourTestRunner.java (Test Runner class)
│       │       └── stepdefinition
│       │           └── YourStepDefinitions.java (Cucumber step definitions)
│       └── resources
│           └── features
│               └── your.feature
            |___extent.properties
            |___extent-config.xml

I am using cucumber CLI to run the test cases from jar.
Main.java
package com.example;
import io.cucumber.core.cli.Main;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {
        // Pass your command-line arguments to the Cucumber CLI Main class
        String[] cucumberArgs = {
            "--glue", "com.example.package.runner.YourTestRunner",
            "--glue", "com.example.package.stepdefinition", 
            "classpath:/features",
            "-t", "@mytag",
            "-p", "com.aventstack.extentreports.cumcumber.adapter.ExtendCucumberAdapter:",
            "-p","json:test/output.json",
            "-p","html:test/output2.html"
        };
        Main.run(cucumberArgs, Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader());
    }
}

extent.properties
extent.reporter.html.start=true
extent.reporter.logger.start=true
extent.reporter.spark.start=true

extent.reporter.html.config=extent-config.xml
extent.reporter.logger.config=extent-config.xml
extent.reporter.spark.config=extent-config.xml

jar structure
|-META-INF
|-com
|-extent-config.xml

When i am running jar
java -jar custom-jar-name.jar

Its giving fileNotfoundExpection (No such file or dictionary)
Here
https://github.com/extent-framework/extentreports-java/blob/0b134ae93730eaf78ca57a1a23993d06d926cba6/src/main/java/com/aventstack/extentreports/config/external/XmlConfigLoader.java#L39
So what i know FileInputStream can only access file from file system. It can't access jar's resources. Is there any way, if this can be resolved ie extent-config.xml  file can be find by com.aventstack.extentreports.config.external from jar itself.
I am expecting to run jar without being dependent on file system ie getting extent-config.xml outside the jar. Other than this i am thinking to generate extent-config.xml file from jar (copy it from jar to file system) every time i run jar.
